# Impact of locks on multithreading performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, locking

I have a simple class designed to play around with threading. It has a member variable, num, which is initialized to 0, and a method called modify which increments and then decrements num a high number of times. When the program runs, it creates two threads which both run modify, and then starts a timer and starts the threads. It uses a while loop to wait for both threads to finish executing, and then stops the timer and prints the time elapsed to the console. The class:

```
public class Threading
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        Threading t = new Threading();
        t.demo();
    }

    private int num = 0;

    public void doThreading()
    {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(modify);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(modify);

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
        timer.Start();

        while (thread1.IsAlive || thread2.IsAlive)
        {

        }

        timer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Took: " + timer.ElapsedMilliseconds + " milliseconds");

        Console.Read();
    }

    public void modify()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            count++;
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

After running the program, num will not be 0 because of race conditions. When I add locks to the modify method so that num is 0 after running the program:

```
public void modify()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            lock (this) { count++; }
            lock (this) { count--; }
        }
    }
```

Then the program takes 8 times as long to execute. I cannot figure out why it would be taking so much longer, I would expect, at most, for it to take 4 times as long to execute. Any idea why it is taking so much longer?

Comment: Lol, why do you expect 4, but not 8? :) Why do you select 4, not 5, not 2, not 11? It's weird to expect this.

Comment: My understanding of multithreading and locks is very limited, I would think that since there are 2  threads, and 2 segments of code, both of which are in separate locks, the slowdown would be by a factor of 2. I wasn't really thinking about overhead from accessing locks, just the cost of forcing threads to wait for each other, but I guess with such simple code the overhead from the accessing the locks could be pretty significant

Comment: Well, wrong question.  It should be "how can `lock` be so astonishingly efficient?"

Answer (score 1):

`lock` can appear to be *quite expensive* in such a case (all you want is to lock incrementing an `int`, i.e. make `count++` *atomic*); use [Interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
public void modify()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref count); 
    }
}
```